# iOS Xcode 6 LaunchImage The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcasset

I deleted my original launchImage image set.

Then went to "App Icons and Launch Images" in the project section of Xcode.

I de-selected "Launch Image Source" and then reselected it. I get the "Migrate launch images to an asset catalog". I choose an asset catalog and "Migrate" and then a launchImage image set opens up.

I add my files, but then I get a red compile warning.

I checked the Plist - no launchimage in there at all.

Previously, I got yellow warnings about Ambiguous content and the files being the wrong sizes - I check and rechecked - they were the right sizes!

How do I fix?

EDIT: I found this in my files. Do I just trash the selected folder?

[image: ios file folder with 2nd images folder]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the project explorer and select the project. Click "Build Phases". At the bottom there's a section called "Copy Bundle Resources." I suspect you'll find two images.xcassets files there and, if so, remove one by highlighting and clicking the minus icon (there are legitimate reasons to have two, or more, but you'd have purposefully done that so it's outside the scope of this answer). On the remaining one add your images to the LaunchImage.

Your reason for adding two isn't clear so I'll add that if you are using multiple targets you can have different images.xcassets files for each target (xcode adds multiples by default). However, if most assets are the same and you don't want to manage multiples, you can use the same in all targets and write add a script to build phases to copy the different assets, like the launch image, over at compile time. This is also done in build phases: add a phase that runs a script then a copy (cp) line to copy images. Needless to say you should do this with very few assets: I use it for launch images and app icons.

Edited to add: there's a new scheme where launch images are in storyboards and/or xib's. I'm assuming that you're not using it because you said you were using the older launch images but, if you are, then just put your launch image in the storyboard/xib launch image file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I deleted the 2nd launch image and get "the set named LaunchImage did not have any applicable content" with an error.

Comment: They were the wrong sizes. That's what caused the error.

Comment: Oh yeah: that'll do it too! At least now you won't have conflicting image cassettes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per your question please visit the below link:
EDIT:
I have tried to regenerate the issue which you are facing. please check your 'images.xcassets' you need to have both 'Launchimage' and 'AppIcon' in 'images.xcassets'. If you don't have either 'LaunchImage' or 'AppIcon' it will generate error.
Based on the image you have added it seems you have deleted image.xcassets from application but not moved to thrash.
 
You can follow the below image to set launch screen images.
1.) Before entering launch image in images.xcassets
[image]
2.) images.xcassets without launch screen image
[image]
3.) Add launch screen image in images.xcassets
[image]
4.) Set launch image in launch Image screen 
 
[image]

This will help you to add new 'image.xcassets' in your application.
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/xcode-assets-xcassets/

 
5.) Folder structure after adding new image xcasset
[image]
6.) Launched the application after deleting and adding new image assets.
[image]
This will help you if you have removed just launch image from your 'images.xcassets' not your images.xcassets.
How to use Image.xcassets:
To set launch screen image and other images in your application. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36Y6rDcKP0&list=PLXCowKcXAVgrCe2Lezv0acRf4adQLshv2

Hope this will be more helpful.

Comment: Followed the tut, now I get error - There are multiple launch image sets named "LaunchImage". How do I fix this?

Comment: You are getting 2 images-2.xcassets is because you you might have deleted launch image but you have might be added another 'images.xcassets' in you application and not deleted the 'images.xcassets' properly you had moved it to thrash. you need to delete 'images-2.xcassets', and add 'images.xcassets' in your application instead of creating new 'Assets Catalog'.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but not helpful at all. Completely confusing.